# Accessibility disabled pop up window impact Selenium Firefox WebDriver test. How to solve it?

Tags: javascript, selenium, firefox

I am using Selenium 3.0.1 for automation test on Firefox Driver (51 version). Every time firefox pops up this window, it impacts the testing process.

I searched online for a solution. Most people suggest to do the following steps:
1. Visit about: config
2. Create a new boolean preference named browser.tabs.remote.force-enable and set its value as true, and change  accessibility.force_disabled preference value to 1, from 0.

I tired, the preference value can be successfully changed/created when I directly launched firefox. But when running the selenium java code, the accessibility window still comes out. Check the preference value, they did not get changed. I could not change it neither in this selenium driven webpage.

Could anyone help solve this problem? Thanks very much. [image]

```
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.setPreference("browser.tabs.remote.force-enable", true);
        profile.setPreference("accessibility.force_disabled",1);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:/D-Download/geckodriver/geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
//      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/");

        driver.switchTo().frame(0);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // Click on textbox so that datepicker will come
        driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker")).click();
```

Comment: Have you created a profile with this setting? http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/custom-firefox-profile/

Comment: Please post the code you are using to set the browser options and launch the browser.

Comment: I have attached my codes with set preference. It helped block the window.

Comment: But looks like the function of the code got impacted as well. It could not perform the 1st click function.